# Canadian study visa refused due to having family ties there

Tags: visas, canada, visa-refusals, study

Canadian study visa refused due to having family ties there(my parents have PR and staying in Canada). Should I reapply? If yes how to prove them I am going to come back? Should I consider the option of applying for the US after this refusal? I genuinely want to go to study only. Please help.

Comment: Hello Anonymous, question about long-term residence should be asked on Expatriates SE.